# Не работают стили для кнопок на сайте

Tags: html, css

Не правильно  отображаются кнопки `#reg_auth`.  Кнопки `Вход и регистрации`. Пожалуйста помогите. Кнопки `#reg_auth>a>div.btn{ border-bottom: 2px solid rgba`

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Saira+Condensed');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

a {
  color: #fa713e;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all.6s ease;
}

a:hover {
  color: #c34f34;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all.6s ease;
}

img {
  max-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto\9;
  transition: all 3s ease-out;
}

hr {
  display: black;
  height: 1px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  float: left;
  background-color: #316ac6;
  width: 99.4%;
  padding: 0.3%;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #5580c6;
}

header>div#logo>a>img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
}

header>div#logo>a {
  color: white;
}

header>div#logo>a>span {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-family: 'Saira Condensed', sans-serif;
}

@media (min-width: 936px) {
  header>div#logo>a>img {
    margin-left: 2%;
  }
  #logo {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
  }
  #about {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
  }
  #reg_auth {
    float: right;
    width: 30%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 935px) and (min-width: 525px) {
  header>div#logo>a>img {
    margin-left: 15%;
  }
  #logo {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
  }
  #about {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
  }
  #reg_auth {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 524px) {
  header>div#logo>a>img {
    margin-left: 5%;
  }
  #logo {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #about {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
  }
  #reg_auth {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
  }
}

#about {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Rammetto One', cursive;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#about>a {
  color: white;
}

#about>a:hover {
  color: #dfdfdf;
  border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
}

#about>a:last-child {
  margin-left: 10%;
}

#reg_auth>a {
  color: white;
}

#reg_auth>a>div.btn {
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(217, 91, 72, 1);
  margin-top: 7px;
}

#reg_auth>a>div.btn {
  border-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 9px;
}

#reg_auth>a>div.btn {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 3%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px 9px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  background-color: rgba(236, 101, 80, 1);
  text-shadow: #454545 0 0 2px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="logo">
    <a href="index.html" title="Главная страница">
      <img src="img/wolksvagen.png" alt="Главная страница" />
      <span>Wolksvagen</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="about">
    <a href="" title="Узнать больше о Wolksvagen">Реклама</a>
    <a href="" title="Обратная связь">Обратная связь</a>
  </div>

  <div id="reg_auth">
    <a href="" title="Личная страница">
      <div id="btn">
        Вход
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="" title="Регистрация">
      <div id="btn">
        Регистрация
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Не плохо было бы `html` увидеть....

Comment: Добавил в конце

Comment: я хочу вот такие кнопки http://zornet.ru/_ld/77/56065768.png над #reg_auth

Comment: Edgar4914410, я понял уже...)))  ответил тебе посмотри комментарии  в коде  ответеа

Comment: Air не работал.....................

Comment: Странно, а тут почему работает?

Comment: спасибо !!! очень очень

Comment: а почему не изменяет цвет кнопки сразу скрывали когда измену

Answer (score 4):

Немного изменил ответ, добавил для `header background` разные цвета, что бы было наглядно видно, что, когда  и как меняется....  Обрати внимания на комментарии в коде....

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Saira+Condensed');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

a {
  color: #fa713e;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all.6s ease;
}

a:hover {
  color: #c34f34;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all.6s ease;
}

img {
  max-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto\9;
  transition: all 3s ease-out;
}

hr {
  display: black;
  height: 1px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  float: left;
  background-color: #316ac6;
  width: 99.4%;
  padding: 0.3%;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #5580c6;
}

header>div#logo>a>img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
}

header>div#logo>a {
  color: white;
}

header>div#logo>a>span {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-family: 'Saira Condensed', sans-serif;
}

#about {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Rammetto One', cursive;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#about>a {
  color: white;
}

#about>a:hover {
  color: #dfdfdf;
  border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
}

#about>a:last-child {
  margin-left: 10%;
}

#reg_auth>a {
  color: white;
}

#reg_auth>a>div.btn {
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(217, 91, 72, 1);
  margin-top: 7px;
}

#reg_auth>a>div.btn {
  border-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 9px;
}

#reg_auth>a>div.btn {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 3%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px 9px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  background-color: rgba(236, 101, 80, 1);
  text-shadow: #454545 0 0 2px;
}


/*==================================*/


/*@media (max-width: 524px)*/

@media (max-width: 524px) {
  header {
    background: red;
  }
  header>div#logo>a>img {
    margin-left: 5%;
  }
  #logo {
    width: 100%;
  }
  /* тут у тебя пропадают кнопки  потому что*/
  /* строка ниже  display: none; */
  #about {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
  }
  #reg_auth {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
  }
}


/*@media (max-width: 524px)*/


/*==================================*/


/*++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++*/


/*==================================*/


/*@media (max-width: 935px) and (min-width: 525px)*/

@media (max-width: 935px) and (min-width: 525px) {
  header {
    background: green;
  }
  header>div#logo>a>img {
    margin-left: 15%;
  }
  #logo {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
  }
  #about {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
  }
  #reg_auth {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
  }
}


/*@media (max-width: 935px) and (min-width: 525px)*/


/*==================================*/


/*++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++*/


/*==================================*/


/* а тут как я понял ты несколько не правильно медиа запрос оформил*/


/* было @media (min-width: 936px) {*/


/* стало  @media (max-width: 1236px) and ( min-width: 936px)*/


/*это для примера (max-width: 1236px) and*/


/* а в медиа уже пропиши те стили которые тебе нужны*/

@media (max-width: 1236px) and ( min-width: 936px) {
  header {
    background: orange;
  }
  header>div#logo>a>img {
    margin-left: 2%;
  }
  #logo {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
  }
  #about {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
  }
  #reg_auth {
    float: right;
    width: 30%;
  }
}


/*@media (min-width: 936px)*/


/*==================================*/
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="logo">
    <a href="index.html" title="Главная страница">
      <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c628028/v628028911/1884a/0osNxl4Lxao.jpg" alt="Главная страница" />
      <span>Wolksvagen</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="about">
    <a href="" title="Узнать больше о Wolksvagen">Реклама</a>
    <a href="" title="Обратная связь">Обратная связь</a>
  </div>

  <div id="reg_auth">
    <a href="" title="Личная страница">
      <!-- <div id="btn"> У тебя id btn -->
      <!-- а в css class btn  #reg_auth>a>div.btn { -->
      <!-- изменил строку ниже id на class -->
      <div class="btn">
        Вход
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="" title="Регистрация">
      <!-- изменил строку ниже id на class -->
      <div class="btn">
        Регистрация
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</header>
```